# How to str_replace on two matches

Tags: php

I like to replace `[HANDLE]` and `[HASHTAG]` in the same `$tweet` how can i combine these 2 lines?

```
$tweet = str_replace('[HANDLE]', $handle, $tweetStrings[$key]); 
$tweet = str_replace('[HASHTAG]', $tagStrings, $tweetStrings[$key]);
```

--------------update

```
$tagStrings = array(
0 => '1',
1 => '2',
2 => '3',
3 => '4',
4 => '5',
5 => '6'
);

foreach ($handles as $handle) {

    if(strlen($handle) > 0) {

        $key = rand(0, count($tweetStrings));

        $tweet = str_replace('[HANDLE]', $handle, $tweetStrings[$key]); 
        $tweet = str_replace('[HASHTAG]', $tagStrings, $tweet);

        echo $tweet . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

code output : hello **@twitterName** some more text, have a look http://website.com **Array**

so its not replacing the **str_replace('[HASHTAG]** with a number between 1/6 but its showing **Array**

Comment: read the manual? http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: Just keep it 2 seperate lines for more readability?

Comment: If you didn't already saw it you can take a tour here: http://stackoverflow.com/tour and see how the site works :D

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a array like this:

```
$tweet = str_replace(array('[HASHTAG]', '[HANDLE]'), array($tagStrings, $handle), $tweetStrings[$key]);
```

For more information about `str_replace()` see the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

And a quote from there:

> **search:**
>   The value being searched for, otherwise known as the needle. **An array may be used to designate multiple needles.**
>
> **replace:**
>   The replacement value that replaces found search values. **An array may be used to designate multiple replacements.**

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I'd keep it 2 seperate lines for better readabilty of the code.

```
$tweet = str_replace('[HANDLE]', $handle, $tweetStrings[$key]);
foreach ($tagStrings as $tag) {
    $tweet = str_replace('[HASHTAG]', $tag, $tweet);
}
```

Comment: if i use this the "[HASHTAG]" is replaced with "Array"

Comment: Is the tagstring always an array from 1 to 6?

Comment: it was just to test but it will probably 4 or 5 different tags

Answer (score 0):

You can simply replace with an array:

```
$tweet = str_replace(
        ['[HANDLE]','[HASHTAG]'], // array with values to be replaced
        [$handle,$tagStrings],    // array with replacing values 
        $tweetStrings[$key]       // string 
);
```

Comment: Probably because of the short array syntax `[]` making the code unusable prior to PHP 5.4 but hey... I didn't downvote it. I only downvote stuff during full planetary conjunctions.

Comment: But we are in 2015, using php 5.3 is eval :) @holodoc